# RecyclerView с группами

Tags: android, kotlin

Какой компонент тут используется? Это RecyclerView с разными ViewHolder? А как добавить возможность раскрывать/скрывать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Все что касается UI - то там нет никаких стандартов. Это может быть все что угодно, и я думаю, что ребята из Сбербанка там вообще реализовывали свою View.

Что вы можете сделать для похожего эффекта? Мне напрашивается пару самых очевидных вариантов:

- Как вы и заметили это может быть `RecyclerView` с разными `ViewHolder-ами`. Каждый `ViewHolder` это отдельная `View` в которой скрыта вся логика (в том числе сворачивания и разворачивания). Для этого вам скорее всего придется использовать какой-то самописный [CompoundView](https://medium.com/@Sserra90/android-writing-a-compound-view-1eacbf1957fc).

  В чем тут проблема: если там будет много сложной логики - вам придется очень заморочиться с тем чтоб это все сделать работоспособным и потом поддерживать.
- В целом это может быть какой-нибудь `NestedScrollView` в который вы ручками будете добавлять фрагменты (каждый элемент == `Fragment`). Внутри фрагмента вы будете работать как с отдельным маленьким экраном, где и опишете свою логику.

  Сложность тут в том, что вам возможно придется решать проблемы скролла и других штук которые уже реализованы в `RecyclerView`.

Но тут может быть и миллион других вариантов. Компании такого уровня очень часто пишут свои решения. Это могут быть как просто небольшие доработки уже существующих инструментов, так и полностью с нуля написанные элементы UI где есть гора логики.

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать с помощью вложенного адаптера.
Анимацию можно прикрутить с помощью `MaterialContainerTransform`.
Например нам надо сделать раскрываемые/скрываемые списки.

Создаем основной адаптер `ExpandableAdapter`

```
class ExpandableAdapter(
private val items: List<Item>,
private val nestedClickListener: (String) -> Unit,
private val transitionFunc: (View, View, ConstraintLayout) -> Unit,
private val transitionReverse: (View, View, ConstraintLayout) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableAdapter.ExpandableViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ExpandableViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
)

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExpandableViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    with(holder) {
        text.text = item.text
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            when (list.visibility) {
                VISIBLE -> {
                    transitionReverse(list, text, rootLayout)
                    Handler().postDelayed({ list.visibility = GONE }, 550)
                }
                GONE -> {
                    transitionFunc(text, list, rootLayout)
                    list.visibility = VISIBLE
                }
            }
            list.adapter = NestedAdapter(item.nestedItems) { nestedClickListener(it) }
        }
    }
}

class ExpandableViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val rootLayout: ConstraintLayout = view.root_layout
    val text: TextView = view.text
    val list: RecyclerView = view.recycler
}
}
```

И вложенный `NestedAdapter`

```
class NestedAdapter(
private val items: List<String>,
private val clickListener: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NestedAdapter.NestedViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = NestedViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
)

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NestedViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    with(holder) {
        text.text = item
        itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(item) }
    }
}

class NestedViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val text: TextView = view.text
}
}
```

`Activity`

```
class ExpandableListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list)

    main_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    main_recycler.adapter = ExpandableAdapter(getItems(), {
        Toast.makeText(this, it, LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    },{ startView, endView, rootLayout ->
        beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, startView.getTransform(endView))
    }, { startView, endView, rootLayout ->
        beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, startView.getTransform(endView))
    })
}

private fun getItems() = listOf(
    Item(12, "первый", listOf("1", "2", "3")),
    Item(13, "второй", listOf("4", "5", "6")),
    Item(24, "третий", listOf("7", "8", "9")),
    Item(37, "четвертый", listOf("10", "11", "12")),
    Item(19, "пятый", listOf("13", "14", "15"))
)

private fun View.getTransform(mEndView: View) = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
    startView = this@getTransform
    endView = mEndView
    addTarget(mEndView)
    pathMotion = MaterialArcMotion()
    duration = 550
    scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
}
```

В айтеме будет `RecyclerView` с заголовком:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="@android:string/unknownName" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    tools:itemCount="5"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`Item`

```
data class Item(
val id: Int,
val text: String,
val nestedItems: List<String>
)
```

`activity_expandable_list`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".expandable.ExpandableListActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: было бы отлично, если дополнили бы ответ и добавили бы Item и недостающие лаяуты. Спасибо

Comment: @DuosDuo ок сейчас