# Как сделать список в списке с разными типами переменных при использовании RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть 4 класса с разными  типами данных. И они вложены друг в друга. Пример: [

```
  {
    "id":1 ,
    "name": "мм",
    "username": "ааа",
    "address": {
      "street": "аааа",
      "city": "ааа",
     "geo": {
        "lat": "нн",
        "lng": "нн"
      }
    },
    "phone": "ааааааа",
     "company": {
      "name": "рррр",
 
    }
  },
  {
   "id":1 ,
    "name": "мм",
    "username": "ааа",
    "address": {
      "street": "аааа",
      "city": "ааа",
     "geo": {
        "lat": "нн",
        "lng": "нн"
      }
    },
    "phone": "ааааааа",
     "company": {
      "name": "рррр",
  }
```

Не могу понять, как мне сделать список RecyclerView. Уверенна, что вся суть в том, что я неправильно определяю логику метода  getItemViewType(int position). Сто раз перечитала ответы по этой ссылке [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4v8P.png) , но веравно не получается.
Может быть у кого-то будут какие-то мысли. Спасибо заранее.
Вот как мой класс выглядит сейчас:

```
public class ResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
       private static int TYPE_USER = 0;
        private static int TYPE_ADDRESS = 1;
        private static int TYPE_GEO = 2;
        private static int TYPE_COMPANY = 3;
    
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private List<User> users;
        
        public ResultAdapter(List<User> users) {
                this.users = users;
                this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
           }
        
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
              @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            if (viewType == TYPE_ADDRESS) {
                return new AddressViewHolder(view);
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_USER) {
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_GEO) {
                return new GeoViewHolder(view);
            } else
                return new CompanyViewHolder(view);
        }
        
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
               final User user = users.get(position/4);
                if (holder instanceof UsersViewHolder) {
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).id.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).name.setText(user.getName());
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).userName.setText(user.getUsername());
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).email.setText(user.getEmail());
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).phone.setText(user.getPhone());
            ((UsersViewHolder) holder).website.setText(user.getWebsite());
    
                } else if (holder instanceof AddressViewHolder) {
                    Address address = user.getAddress();
          ((AddressViewHolder) holder).street.setText(address.getStreet());
          ((AddressViewHolder) holder).suite.setText(address.getSuite());
          ((AddressViewHolder) holder).city.setText(address.getCity());
          ((AddressViewHolder) holder).zipcode.setText(address.getZipcode());
                } else if (holder instanceof CompanyViewHolder) {
                    Company company = user.getCompany();
           ((CompanyViewHolder) holder).companyName.setText(company.getName());
       ((CompanyViewHolder) holder).catchPhrase.setText(company.getCatchPhrase());
           ((CompanyViewHolder) holder).bs.setText(company.getBs());
                } else if (holder instanceof GeoViewHolder) {
                    Geo geo = user.getAddress().getGeo();
                    ((GeoViewHolder) holder).lat.setText(geo.getLat());
                    ((GeoViewHolder) holder).lng.setText(geo.getLng());
                }
            }
        
        
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
               return users.size()*4;
            }
             @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position % 4 == 0) {
                return TYPE_USER;
            } else if (position % 4 == 1) {
                return TYPE_ADDRESS;
            } else if (position % 4 == 2) {
                return TYPE_GEO;
            } else return TYPE_COMPANY;
        }
```

и классы модели соответственно:

```
public class User{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private Address address;
    private String phone;
    private String wedsite;
    private Company company;
}
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String suite;
    private String city;
    private Geo geo;}
public class Geo{
    private String lat;
    private String lng;}
public class Company{
    private String name;}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167517/265051

Comment: @ Cyphe, спасибо. но мне нужен не раскрывающий список. а простой писок

Comment: а какая разница. просто уберите логику изменения видимости и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы явно неправильно вычисляете кол-во элементов списка, юзера для отображаемого элемента и тип отображаемого элемента.

Кратко если, то поправить можно примерно так:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return users.size()*4;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position%4;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User user = users.get(position/4);
```

Comment: ♦, в том и дело. Я не понимаю, как мне получить позицию,например, класса Geo.

Comment: @Monica, у вас нет никакой позиции у Geo класса. Положим, у вас 2 юзера, содержащих компанию и адрес, который содержит гео. Тогда, если вы хотите всю эту информацию в отдельных ячейках общим списком отобразить, то вам надо 8 ячеек. В 0 и 4 - будет юзер, в 1 и 5 - компанию, во 2 и 6 - адрес, в 3 и 7 - гео. Т.к. самих юзеров у вас всего 2, а ячеек - 8, то для 0-3 ячеек юзер будет `position/4`. Также и для всех следующих.

Comment: ♦, т.е. в методе getItemViewType я прописываю так:  `<int TYPE_USER = 1; int TYPE_ADDRESS = 2;    if (position ==0 || position == 4)  {   return TYPE_USER;   }  else if (position ==1 || position == 5){return TYPE_ADDRESS;>`    а в методе onBindViewHolder так: `<final User user = users.get(position/4);   if (holder instanceof UsersViewHolder) {   ((UsersViewHolder) holder).id.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));...      else if (holder instanceof AddressViewHolder) { Address address = user.getAddress();
            ((AddressViewHolder) holder).street.setText(address.getStreet());>`

Comment: Примерно. Точнее верно про вторую часть. Про первую часть - сделайте как я вам в ответе написал - используйте в качестве типа ячейки остаток от деления на 4.

Comment: ♦, спасибо за пояснения,буду пытаться. пока не получается ничего)

Comment: @Monica, если вы напишите что именно не получается - возможно я смогу подсказать. Возможно вы не скопировали код из моего ответа, как писали раньше в комментарии?

Comment: ♦, я правила вой вопрос. сейчас там код, который я сделала,следуя Вашим рекомендациям.

Comment: И он не работает? Если да - приведите логи ошибок или описание некорректного поведения. Типа должно быть так, а оно по другому.

Comment: ♦, в логах ошибок нету, программа отрабатывает. просто отображает неверно. вот так, как я вставила картинку в вопрос. т.е. в первом юзере отображается данные юзера. во втором юзере отоброжаются данные адрес, в тертьем юзере отображаются данные гео, в 4 юзере отображаются данные компании. и дальше у остальных юзеров (их 10) отображаются только данные компании.

Comment: Может у вас что-то не то в самих данных? Покажите как вы данные извлекаете и переводите их из Json в java объекты. Также вам не стоит использовать одну и ту же разметку для всех холдеров. Она должна быть разная. Т.е. вам надо ваш файл разметки разбить на 4 разных файла и их использовать в соответствующих холдерах.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб♦ , Вы имеете ввиду, что для каждого  ViewHolder  метод inflate должен "надувать" свой вью, не один и тот же?

Comment: @Monica, да, всё верно. Если ячейки разные - должны быть и вьюхи разные быть.

Comment: ♦ , Вы абсолютно правы! В коде выше я ничего не меняла, просто для каждого пункта списка сделала отдельные файлы list_item. И сейчас все отображается как нужно. Спасибо Вам большое за помощь!!!

Comment: Пожалуйта) А вообще - обратите внимание на ответ @Barmaley - он концептуально вернее) В моём ответе в основном как ваш уже готовый код заставить работать. А так - надо бы в отдельные ячейки всё это запихнуть, разбив объект юзера на части и составив список данных из этих частей - так получится гораздо гибче. Ну и библиотеки есть, сильно облегчающие такой подход.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб♦, с самого начала, до этого варианта кода, я пробовала так, как советовал @Barmaley , но,  я читаю данные GET запросом из JSON файла, у меня некорректно работал Call<List<User>> getUsers() метод.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал по другому:

1. Завел бы корневой абстрактный класс `UserInfo`, от которого наследуются класса `User`, `Address`, `Geo` и `Company`
2. В адаптере завел бы список `List<UserInfo> userInfos` (вместо `List<User> users`)

В этом случае исчезает вся эта шелуха связанная с арифметикой `users.size()*4` и т.д. - код становится чистым и понятным, типа:

```
int getItemViewType(int position) {
    UserInfo userInfo = userInfos.get(position);
    if(userInfo instanceOf(User) ) {
        return TYPE_USER;
    }
    //blah-blah
}
```

и т.д. - дальше все понятно.