# Реализовать раскрывающийся элемент списка

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Суть следующая: есть список элементов, при нажатии на которые открывается дочерний фрагмент, в котором содержится подробная информация о выбранном элементе. Каким образом можно реализовать, чтобы по нажатию на элемент списка открывался не дочерний фрагмент, а в том же окне, во фрагменте со списком - вся информация вылезала из под элемента списка. То есть что-то на подобие раскрывающегося меню. Только При раскрытии элемента не список, а табличка в виде фрагмента. Может кто-то сталкивался, делал такое, или видел как это делается?

Comment: если я правильно понял то вам нужно что то вроде этой библиотеки? https://github.com/hendraanggrian/recyclerview-expandable

Comment: Да, похоже на правду, спасибо, буду изучать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167517/265051