# Анимация выпадающего списка Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Есть Android-приложение.
Есть ли возможность в андроиде сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "More", которая описана в list_item.xml под названием категории выезжал плавно еще один список ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: контекстное меню устроит?

Comment: Однозначно, что нет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167517/265051